# psql upsert results in noncontinuous id

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a postgresql (>9.5) table with primary_key `id` and a unique key `col`. When I use

`INSERT INTO table_a (col) VLUES('xxx') ON CONFLICT(col) DO NOTHING;`

to perform a upsert, let's say a row with an id `1` is generated.

If I run the sql again, nothing will happen, but actually the id `2` will be generated and abandoned.

Then if I insert a new record, for example,

`INSERT INTO table_a (col) VLUES('yyy') ON CONFLICT(col) DO NOTHING;`

Another row with id `3` will be generated and id `2` is wasted!

Is there anyway to avoid this waste?

Comment: No, there is no way. Unless you think you will reach the 64bit integer limit, i also would not consider it "waste"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably `id` is a `serial`. Under the hood this causes a `nextval()` call from a sequence. A number `nextval()` once returned will never be returned again. And the call of `nextval()` happens before checking for possible conflicts.

From ["9.16. Sequence Manipulation Functions"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-sequence.html):

> `nextval`
>
> (...)
>
> **Important:** To avoid blocking concurrent transactions that obtain numbers from the same sequence, a `nextval` operation is never rolled back; that is, once a value has been fetched it is considered used and will not be returned again. This is true even if the surrounding transaction later aborts, or if the calling query ends up not using the value. For example an `INSERT` with an `ON CONFLICT` clause will compute the to-be-inserted tuple, including doing any required `nextval` calls, before detecting any conflict that would cause it to follow the `ON CONFLICT` rule instead. Such cases will leave unused "holes" in the sequence of assigned values. Thus, PostgreSQL sequence objects **cannot be used to obtain "gapless" sequences.**

Concluded that means, that the answer to your question is no, there is no way to avoid this unless you generate the values yourself somehow.